# Using equals() in if statement to check for nullability

Tags: java, if-statement, nullpointerexception

I have an if statement which is returning a NullPointerException.

```
Object obj;
if (obj.toString().equals("string"))
```

The expected result is a NullPointerException as obj has no value assigned to it, and it's being compared to a String.

Now considering the condition below

```
Object obj;
if (obj.toString().equals(null))
```

obj still being null (as I haven't assigned a value to it), although shouldn't my if statement return as true since obj is being compared to null?

Comment: hmm .. this looks like you might be mis-using the toString - the general rule is to never-ever override it for application reasons, so generally there is no need to check its return value. There are odd corner cases, though :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to explicitly check against the literal value `null`. In the following example, if the non-null check fails, it wont' run the statement after the `&&`; the first check short-circuits the rest of the expression

```java
Object obj;
if (obj != null && obj.toString().equals("string")) { 
  //do something 
}
else { 
  //do another something 
}
```

#### Note:

- `null` is a literal value *(similar to true and false)*. So you should not be comparing it like a `String`.

Comment: obj.toString.equals("string") doesn't compile

Comment: @tgdavies good catch. Edited the answer to include the function call.